# angularjs smart-table programmatically sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I have a table set up using the smart-table plug in for AngularJS. Everything appears to work nicely. Rather than having the user click on the table header to trigger a sort, I'd like to programmatically trigger sorting from my Angular controller. I do not see a way of doing this in the documentation here:

http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this on JSFiddle, might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/js64b/14/

```
<script type="text/javascript" ng:autobind
src="http://code.angularjs.org/0.10.5/angular-0.10.5.js"></script>

<table ng:controller="SortableTableCtrl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng:repeat="(i,th) in head" ng:class="selectedCls(i)" ng:click="changeSorting(i)">{{th}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng:repeat="row in body.$orderBy(sort.column, sort.descending)">
            <td>{{row.a}}</td>
            <td>{{row.b}}</td>
            <td>{{row.c}}</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gave you a vote but I haven't marked this is as the answer. Is this the correct approach for smart-table? I'd rather than write additional code to manage sorting myself if smart-table provides something built in... although I'd assume it does something similar behind the scenes. 
Edit: In the words of Bill O'Reilly... F*** IT. We'll do it live!!.... marking this as the answer. It'll do what I need.

Comment: Hahaha! Beebunny, enjoy :) Sorry I don't know smart-table though

Comment: This isn't smart-table?

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack i found on how to do this is by setting the table header st-sort property and then triggering a click() on that element

```
<tr>
  <th id="myelement" st-sort="date" st-sort-default="reverse">Date</th> 
  ...
</tr>
```

Then later:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('myelement').click()        
    }, 
  0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the 'angular' way to do this. Write a directive. This directive will have access to the smart table controller. It will be able to call the controller's sort by function. We will name the new directive stSortBy.

The below HTML includes the standard smart table syntatic sugar. The only new attribute directive here is st-sort-by. That's where the magic will happen. It's bound to a scoped variable sortByColumn. This is a string value of the column to sort

```html
<table st-sort-by="{{sortByColumn"}}" st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection">
<thead>
<tr>
<th st-sort="column1">Person</th>
<th st-sort="column2">Person</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>

<button ng-click="toggleSort()">Toggle sort columns!</button>
```

Here is the stSortBy directive that hooks into the st table controller

```js
app.directive('stSortBy', function() {
    return {
        require: 'stTable',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            attr.$observe('stSortBy', function (newValue) {
                if(newValue) {
                    // ctrl is the smart table controller
                    // the second parameter is for the sort order
                    ctrl.sortBy(newValue, true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the controller. The controller sets the sort by in it's scope

```js
app.controller("MyTableWrapperCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.sortByColumn = 'column2';
  
  $scope.toggleSort = function() {
     $scope.sortByColumn = $scope.sortByColumn === 'column2' ? 'column1' : 'column2';
     // The time out is here to guarantee the attribute selector in the directive
     // fires. This is useful is you do a programmatic sort and then the user sorts
     // and you want to programmatically sort back to the same column. This forces a sort, even if you are sorting the same column twice.
     $timeout(function(){
      $scope.sortByColumn = undefined;
     }, 0);
  };
}]);
```